# How to get height of Header component in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been searching for a good way to get the height of the Header component of a react-native stack navigator to no avail. I've come across a [stale, complicated answer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2411#issuecomment-363622377) that doesn't provide the header height specifically, but seems to unavoidably combine the bottom tab bar height as well. I'd like to know how to calculate the height of just the navigation header and status bar with react-navigation.

For reference, my project is using react-navigation 3.11 however I would happily attempt an upgrade if there is a solution involving features exclusive to 4.x. I have checked [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#adjusting-header-styles) and see how I could supply a static header style but I don't want this. I'd just like to be able to access the navigation header style's height attribute from within a view.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this. The solution mentioned below is for the stack navigator and not for the native stack navigator.

Answer (score 1):

In React Navigation >4.x you can use `HeaderHeightContext` or `useHeaderHeight` with [React's Context API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x/#library-exports) to get the height of the header:

```
import { HeaderHeightContext } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// ...

<HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
  {headerHeight => (
    /* ... */
  )}
</HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
```

or

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// ...

const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

Comment: according to this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight you should use @react-navigation/elements to get useHeaderHeight